# How to read content from ms word files using Jakarta POI

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I've included jakarta-poi-1.5.1-final-20020615.jar file to read content from ms word.

I am unable to do this ...can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Here is [quick guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html)

Comment: A small clarification can i use this guide for jakarta poi....i am not using apache poi

Comment: @satheesh what is jakarta poi? I think there is only one apache project for ms windows called poi http://poi.apache.org/

Comment: sir,i downloaded jakarta-poi-1.5.1-final-20020615.jar and in this one i didnt find HWPFDocument class to read word doc ...if you dont mine can u check this jar file

Comment: @satheesh this is the part of poi that I think it is for formulaparser http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/STUVWXYZ/Downloadjakartapoi151final20020615jar.htm for ms word you should download .jar from here http://poi.apache.org/download.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to move to a newer version of POI - the one you're on is about 9 years old! Grab the latest version of POI (it's just Apache POI now, hasn't been Apache Jakarta POI for a few years now), you'll want either 3.7 Final or 3.8 beta 2 as of writing.

Then, have a read through the [HWPF docs](http://poi.apache.org/hwpf/index.html) and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code with apache-poi

```
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(fileName));
    List<XWPFTable> table = doc.getTables();
    for (XWPFTable xwpfTable : table) {
        List<XWPFTableRow> row = xwpfTable.getRows();
        for (XWPFTableRow xwpfTableRow : row) {
            List<XWPFTableCell> cell = xwpfTableRow.getTableCells();
            for (XWPFTableCell xwpfTableCell : cell) {
                if (xwpfTableCell != null) {
                    System.out.println(xwpfTableCell.getText());
                    String s = xwpfTableCell.getText();
                    for (XWPFParagraph p : xwpfTableCell.getParagraphs()) {
                        for (XWPFRun run : p.getRuns()) {
                            for (XWPFPicture pic : run.getEmbeddedPictures()) {
                                byte[] pictureData = pic.getPictureData().getData();
                                System.out.println("picture : " + pictureData);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This method will print the internal runs of the entire document so you will be able to compare the values based on xml text.

```
for (XWPFParagraph p : doc.getParagraphs()) {
    for (XWPFRun r : p.getRuns()) {
       String text = r.getText(0);
       System.out.println(text);
     }
}
```