# Search content of Ms-word files using Java

Tags: java, ms-word

My requirement is search the content from the more than one MS-word or Ms-Excel file that are placed in the same folder. how can i implement this using java Technologies? pls give me an overview.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can make fully use of third party components available, such as Apache POI(free) or ASPOSE(paid). Their documents should have designated the way to retrieve the data in MS documents.

Refer to:
[How to read content from ms word files using Jakarta POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990139/how-to-read-content-from-ms-word-using-jakarta-poi)

Answer (score 1):

Can use [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) to easily extract the content of the microsoft word file and search through the text.

Sample code -

```
File f = new File("path to file");
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
ContentHandler contenthandler = new BodyContentHandler();
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
metadata.set(Metadata.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY, f.getName());
Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
parser.parse(is, contenthandler, metadata);
System.out.println(metadata.get(Metadata.TITLE));
System.out.println(contenthandler.toString());
```

You can search through the contenthandler.toString() which is the content.

Comment: Thank you Jayendra. I hope your information will be very much useful for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You may try Aspose.Words for Java and Aspose.Cells for Java to [extract contents from Microsoft Word](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/java-components/aspose.words-for-java/howto-extract-content-using-documentvisitor.html) and [get data from Microsoft Excel](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/java-components/aspose.cells-for-java/working-with-data.html) documents respectively. Please note that these two components do not require Microsoft Office installed on the development or deployment machines. You may [try these file processing components](http://www.aspose.com/community/files/default.aspx) at your end.

Disclosure: I work as a developer evangelist at Aspose.